# Jest: only supported when running Babel asynchronously

Tags: node.js, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

It seems to be something wrong in my configuration but I'm not able to find what is my problem.

When I try to run a test with this command:

```
npx jest ./__tests__/ddbb.test.js
```

I receive this error:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/ddbb.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    You appear to be using a native ECMAScript module configuration file, which is only supported when running Babel asynchronously.
        at /home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics4/server/babel.config.js

      at loadPartialConfigSync (node_modules/@babel/core/src/config/index.ts:49:60)
      at loadPartialConfigSync (node_modules/@babel/core/src/config/index.ts:68:14)
      at ScriptTransformer._getCacheKey (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:228:41)
      at ScriptTransformer._getFileCachePath (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:27)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:525:32)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:674:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:726:19)
```

My configuration files are:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Backend server for basketmetrics",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean-build": "rm -rf ./build",
    "_comment3": "Script para generar el código de servidor de producción",
    "build:test": "webpack --mode production",
    "start:test": "NODE_ENV=test nodemon --experimental-specifier-resolution=node server/index.mjs",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node server/index.mjs",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "helmet": "^7.1.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.23.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.6",
    "@babel/register": "^7.22.15",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }, 
  "type": "module"
}
```

**jest.config.cjs**

```
module.exports = {
    moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "mjs"],
    transform: {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
    },
  };
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}]],
};
```

What am I doing wrong?